# Ubuntu USB boot not working from Grub 2 screen

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard

Ran into a problem with a windows rollback interfering with an update. Now computer gives me 0xc00000034 error on the BCD file.
Trying to access a Toshiba laptop computer using Ubuntu 20.04 boot from a USB stick, loaded using Rufus.

Select boot order on startup, select USB with Ubuntu on. Loads Grub 2.04 screen....and nothing.

Built-in keyboard doesn't respond. Auto-load on selection doesn't work. Timer doesn't change.
Have tried with old-style external keyboard (USB, don't have a PS/2 version).
Have tried all USB ports with both external keyboard and USB stick.

Neither keyboard works, so can't make selections.

Have enabled USB Legacy drivers in Bios. (keyboard will work for Bios). Does not work at Grub screen

No up/down arrows, no page up/down, no e or c.
No response on any keys.

Also tried this on using Fedora boot live USB the day before, same issue.

Problem seems to be at Grub screen. Nothing happens, or can be selected.

Been through forums, but can't find a solution that I haven't tried and listed above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is a "Windows Rollback" and a "BCD file"?   We can't solve Windows problems here.  If your Ubuntu installation media is valid and un-corrupted and your system freezes before you can do anything, it seems like you might have a hardware fault.

Comment: The issue is at the Grub screen, where it does not allow further input and the timer does not countdown. So no auto-selection is possible either. It may be a hardware fault in that the in-built keyboard is not active at the Grub screen, but neither is any other USB device except the USB boot device. 

The computer was installed with Windows 10, 'rollback' was related to windows for correcting an error during an update. I was using Ubuntu for trying access the storage..